# How we can connect and fetch data from DataBase using DbConnection class

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ado.net

How can I use `DbConnection` class to connect to a database (sql server or oracle) and fetch data from any table. I tried with following code, but i got a run time exception like this:

> Error 3   error C2664:
>   'System::Data::SqlClient::SqlDataAdapter::SqlDataAdapter(System::String
>   __gc *,System::String __gc *)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'System::Data::Common::DbConnection __gc *' to 'System::String __gc *'
>   at new SqlDataAdapter(S"select * from [LabOpsStatus]",conn)

```
DbConnection *conn;
conn = new SqlConnection(S"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDb;User Id=user;Password=pw;");
conn->Open();
mySDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(S"select * from [LabOpsStatus]",conn);
```

What is the wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shaheer, you need to create the connection from a provider. I don't think my provider specified as Oracle is correct though.

some c# code again

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle");

DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDb;User Id=user;Password=pw;";

DbCommand cmd = factory.CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from table1";
```

Comment: The problem that you will still have is that once you created the connection for SQL, you cannot use it for Oracle, unless you recreate the connection in the same object for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
string datosConexion = "Data Source=(local);"
        + "Initial Catalog = myDb ; User Id=user;Password=pw;";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(datosConexion))
            {
                con.Open();
                string textoCmd = "select * from [LabOpsStatus]";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(textoCmd, con);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```